# How to get the Rendering Datasource after an AJAX postback

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have the ajax code below:

```js
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/sitecore/SmartAds/GetSmartAddsItem',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

The problem is the `Sitecore.Context.Item.ContextRendering` is `null` in the ajax call.

**Question:** How do I get the rendering datasource during AJAX call?

I found the below code [here](http://www.matthewdresser.com/sitecore/modelbinding-rendering-datasource-ajax-postback-sitecore-mvc), but I am having trouble getting it to work:

```c#
public class FormModelBinderProvider : Dictionary, IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        var binders = from binder in this
                      where binder.Key.IsAssignableFrom(modelType)
                      select binder.Value;

        return binders.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that says that `Dictionary requires 2 type arguments`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MIght be nothing but I can see that the post that your post is referencing has a slightly different ModelBinderProvider signature where the dictionary parameter is defined as `Dictionary<Type, IModelBinder>`

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with your code is that the AJAX request you are making is a 'GET' request rather than a post, so it won't be passing in the hidden field value for the datasource item. To clarify, the article covers situations where a form is posted back, not AJAX GET requests.